# Async Cross Fields Validator

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular14

In a form I have to validate a field considering the value of another field.
i.e. if the first dropdown has value 1 then the second dropdown value must be selected.

To do this I've tried with async validators with no clue.

I add the validator with `.setAsyncValidators`
and the validator of the "second" dropdown looks like this:

```
validateDropDown(formControl: FormControl){
    const parent = formControl.parent!;
    const firstDD = parent.get("firstDropDown")!;
    return firstDD.valueChanges.pipe(
        map ((res) => {
          let isValid = false;
          if (res.id == 1 || res.id == 10) {
            const value = formControl.value.length;
            if (value > 0) {
              isValid = true;
            } else {
              isValid = false;
            }
          } else {
            isValid = true;
          }
            return of (isValid == true ? null : {
              userValid: {
                valid: false
              }
          });
        })
    );
}
```

I know that with that code I can't check the value.length of the second DropDown because the return is only on the first dropdown value change, but that's a secondary issues.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Why not use something like as described in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation)?

Comment: it's **not** async validator (only a validator that involve two formControls)

Comment: I will give a try with control.get and formGroup, I'm adapting an existing code that involves more fields and already uses async validators. Only that two must be evaluated togheter, if first drop-down has specific values the second drop-down is required, for the other values is optional